# Disable sorting on EditItemTemplate in GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, datatables

I'm using responsive DataTable classes in my GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
         CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" CausesValidation="true" />
```

Using the script below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= myGrid.ClientID %>").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": ['_all'] }],
        });
    });
</script>
```

This script disables sort option on all Columns except my first column, which has Edit button that is enabled using `ShowEditButton="true"` of GridView.

I can see rendered HTML in the page, the first column still has `class="sorting_asc"` while all other columns have `class="sorting_disabled"`.  How do I disable sorting on the column added by GridView for Edit / Update / Cancel?

Answer (score 0):

you need change `"targets": ['_all']`  to `"targets": '_all'`

**"How do I disable sorting on the column added by GridView for Edit / Update / Cancel?"**

if you want to configure each column separately, look below..

"columnDefs" is object array that columndefinitions. you need  define this `{ "orderable": false, "targets": ['_all'] }`  per each column.

you can prepare `new {"orderable": false ...}` object array on server side by gridview edit-update mode.. and inject your script..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= myGrid.ClientID %>").DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "columnDefs": <%= ColumnDefinitions %>,
    });
});
```

for server side..

```
    public string ColumnDefinitions;
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> columns = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
            columns.Add(new { orderable = !(myGrid.Columns[i] is CommandField) });

        ColumnDefinitions = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns);
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Comment: I tried `{ "orderable": false, "targets": ['_all'] }` already and it doesn't disable sorting at all.  The arrows present on every column inspite of this

Comment: I'm not trying to control each column separately, I want to disable sorting for all columns.  It is disabling with my script for all columns except for the one added with CommandField.

Comment: change `{ "orderable": false, "targets": ['_all'] }` to `{ "orderable": false, "targets": '_all'}`

Comment: yes, I tried that too but the result is same; I see sorting arrows on all columns